# Evaluation of reduction along all dimensions in Eigen3 Tensor class

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to compute the Frobenius norm of a tensor using the Tensor module of the Eigen3 library.

Here is my code:

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main ()
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> t(4, 3, 2);
  t.setRandom();

  // Computing the Frobenius norm. The result is a single scalar value.
  const auto frob_norm_op = t.square().sum().sqrt().eval();

  // Is there an easier way to extract the scalar value ?
  Eigen::TensorEvaluator<const decltype(frob_norm_op), Eigen::DefaultDevice>
    frob_norm_eval (frob_norm_op, Eigen::DefaultDevice());
  const double frob_norm = frob_norm_eval.coeff(0);

  return 0;
}
```

This works, but I guess that there should be an easier way to extract `frob_norm` from `frob_norm_op`. Any ideas?

[The example](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/default/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/README.md?fileviewer=file-view-default#markdown-header-reduction-along-all-dimensions%22this%20example%22) of the documentation throws a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

I reply myself.
I don't know if it is the best way, but it is sorter than the previous one:

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

int main ()
{
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> t(4, 3, 2);
  t.setRandom();

  const Eigen::Tensor<double, 0> frob_norm_tens = t.square().sum().sqrt();
  const double frob_norm = frob_norm_tens.coeff();

  return 0;
}
```